# Issue trying to modify bag contents with python

Tags: python, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've found out that I need a frame_id in my imu message to be able to visualize it in RViz, so I've been trying to add a frame_id to the bags I have.  When I try reading through the messages in the bag I keep getting an error saying "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'secs'"

Here is the code and the output from the terminal:

[image description http://oi60.tinypic.com/2wf4oc0.jpg](http://oi60.tinypic.com/2wf4oc0.jpg)

I think I've managed to establish that the issue is to do with the itemiterator (or whatever it's called) t, but I haven't had any luck trying to cast it to the secs type.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202709/issue-trying-to-modify-bag-contents-with-python/) by [that_guy318](https://answers.ros.org/users/20951/that_guy318/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I remember correctly, the bag.write() takes the topic name, the message and the timestamp as arguments, but you're passing the frame id as the third argument.

Instead of:

```
output.write(topic, msg, msg.header.frame_id)
```

Try using the timestamp from the original bag file:

```
output.write(topic, msg, t)
```

P.S. - Your IMU messages should probably all have the same frame ID

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [that_guy318](https://answers.ros.org/users/20951/that_guy318/) on 2015-02-09**:
Awesome that worked, thanks!  I couldn't find anywhere that actually said what that function was expecting.  RViz is now displaying my acceleration vector too.